# How to know Jquery animate progress?

Tags: jquery

I have a web page which brings another page by sliding from the top... I have achieved this using jquery animate... Now my query is how can i know the percentage of progress of animate() method... Like from the page starts sliding to its completion

Thanks

Comment: Example using `progress`: http://jsbin.com/oguwap/228/edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`step`-callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step), which you pass in the animation options to execute a function on every step. You could look into that.

```
$('#myElement').animate({/*Your animation options.*/}, {
  step: function(current_number){
    /* measure stuff using the first argument passed to this function */
  }
})
```

**EDIT**
[@Rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket) made [a demo](http://jsbin.com/oguwap/5/edit#javascript,html).

Comment: +1, the step callback seems more accurate than using `setInterval`.

Comment: It's also prettier than having a different seperate timeout run _next_ to your animation. Thanks for creating the demo. :)

Comment: I made a [better demo](http://jsbin.com/oguwap/5/edit).  Instead of saving the new height, you can just ask the `fx` object what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you define the time for animation. You could execute the `setInterval` with the corresponding timespan. [Like this](http://jsbin.com/oguwap/edit#javascript,html).

```
$(function() {
  $("#hello").animate({"height":600}, 10000);
  var percent = 0;
  var pointer = setInterval(function() {
    if (percent > 100) {
      clearInterval(pointer);
      return;
    }
    $("#Status").text(percent + "%");
    percent++;
  }, 100);
});
```

**EDIT**

I've added some code to clear interval by the end. [And updated the demo](http://jsbin.com/oguwap/2/edit)

**EDIT**

I've updated the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/oguwap/3/edit) again. Here callback of the `animate` is responsible to stop the interval. However it is not brilliantly accurate.

Comment: You might want to add a callback to `animate` to stop the interval when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [step callback function](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm) that's built into animate() and work out the percentage progress from that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
<style>
#frame{
 width:400px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
</style>


    <div id="progress"></div>
    <div id="frame"></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frame").animate({height:'500'},
        {
        step: function(now, fx) {
        $("#progress").text(now);          
        },
        complete: function(){

        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```