# Run jQuery during jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run jQuery during a jQuery animation?

I've tried

```
$(this).animate({height:0});
//jquery here
```

But that runs after, same with the callback code.

Comment: what are you trying to run exactly when the animation is occurring?

Comment: @anurupr when the old element is animated to height 0, new elements come in the viewport. I am checking what is in the viewport and styling that.

Comment: you should check out `step` or `progress` callbacks for `animate`. You can refer this for more info , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331431/how-to-know-jquery-animate-progress

Comment: @anurupr put that as an answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: the user who answered that should get the credit , not me :)

Comment: i'm just the messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 1.8 and later has a progress parametre where jQuery code can be run inside that happens during the animation:

```
$(this).animate({height:0,
    {
        progress: function(){
            // your code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your question.

HTML

```
<div id="task1"></div>
<div id="anm"></div>
```

CSS

```
#anm{
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background: #000000;
 }
```

Javascript

```
var value = 1;

var myFunction = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("task1").innerHTML = value += 2;
}, 200);

$("#anm").animate({
      height: '200px'  }, 5000,function(){
      clearInterval(myFunction);
});
```

Comment: Yes, now I got your query, try above code and tell if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAnimating = $("#someid").is(':animated');
```

this returns true if is animating.